# Prove ${ Z }_{ 3 }{ \times Z }_{ 4 }\simeq { Z }_{ 12 }$ directly.

Tags: abstract-algebra

$${ Z }_{ 3 }{ \times Z }_{ 4 }\simeq { Z }_{ 12 }$$
Above notations are ideal.

I tried $f(a,b)=4a+3b$
But, I run into a brick wall because of multiplication for homomorphism.
How to prove it?

Comment: What is this supposed to mean: "Above notations are ideal"?

Comment: What does "above notations are ideal" mean? Do you mean "show that [...] is an isomorphism of rings"?

Comment: A.P. Yes. Thanks to your advice(below comment). I solved it just now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NB: I could not entirely understand the question as posted, and here provide a proof that the two sides are isomorphic as additive groups.

I suggest that you write elements of $Z_3 \times Z_4$ as pairs $(a, b)$, where $a$ is in $Z_3$ and $b \in Z_4$. Then the simplest (group) isomorphism $f$ from $Z_{12}$ is 
$$
1 \mapsto (1, 1)
$$
You have to then ask whether $f(c) = 0$ for any value of $c$ other than $0$) (i.e., check that it's injective). Once you've done that, you know it's surjective, because the two sets have the same number of elements.

Let's check injectivity. For an element $c$, we have
$$
f(c) = (c \bmod 3, c \bmod 4)
$$
If that's $(0,0)$, then $c$ is a multiple of both $3$ and $4$; hence must be a multiple of 12 as well, and hence must be 0 in $Z_{12}$.

N.B.2:as @A.P. points out, this is also a homomorphism of rings, for 
\begin{align}
f(cd) &= (cd \bmod 3, cd \bmod 4) \\
&= ((c \bmod 3) (d \bmod 3), (c \bmod 4) (d \bmod 4))\\
&= (c \bmod 3, c \bmod 4) \cdot (d \bmod 3, d \bmod 4) .
\end{align}

Comment: (a,a)(b,b)=(ab,ab)?

Comment: Sorry...what I've proved is that they're isomorphic *as additive groups*. I wasn't claiming anything about multiplication. Was I supposed to? I couldn't quite make sense of the question. Are you hoping to show that they're isomorphic as rings?

Comment: @YSRiemann What is your question? This map is perfectly fine as an isomorphism of rings, too...

Comment: AP: Good point. I should have said that, but since I was answering the group question, I thought I should be honest. :)

Comment: If you wish to show it explicitly, just observe that $([ab]_3,[ab]_4) = ([a]_3[b]_3, [a]_4[b]_4) = ([a]_3,[a]_4)([b]_3,[b]_4)$, where $[x]_n$ is the class of $x$ modulo $n$.

Comment: A.P. AHH... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

How about you use $f : Z_{12} \to Z_4 \times Z_3$ such that $a \to (a\ \text{mod}\ 4, a\ \text{mod}\ 3)$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Use Bézouts identity $4-3=1$. The map is:
$$(a\bmod 3,b\bmod 4)\mapsto 4a-3b\bmod 12.$$

Comment: Then, what is (a,b)(c,d)? Is it (ac,bd)?

Comment: @YSRiemann This map is the *inverse* of John Hughes's map. To show that it is a ring morphism you need to show that $(4a - 3b)(4c - 3d) \equiv 4ac - 3bd \pmod{12}$.